# How to iterate over keys of a generic object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I need to iterate over a large object which is just typed as "object".
It contains an unknown number of objects of the same type.

In older posts I had found solutions using a generator within a custom Symbol.iterator function to make the large object iterable with a for..of loop.

But it seems to me, now in 2017, just using Object.keys is actually easier:

```
Object.keys(bigObject).forEach((key:string)=>{
console.log(bigObject[key]);
});
```

This actually runs just fine! But the TypeScript compiler keeps giving me the error *"error TS7017: Element implicitly h
as an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature"*

Does anybody have an idea what I am missing here? Or what is the current best practice to do such an iteration with ES2015 and TypeScript (2.2.2)?

Comment: You can "type" your object as `any` or `{ [index:string] : any }`

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer, Aleksey! Yeah, that gets rid of the error.

But I am just wondering if this entire approach is what is considered best practice these days? Also with the "object" type just being introduced with TypeScript 2.2.2 I thought this was the way to go when dealing with an object of unknown type...

Comment: This approach is perfectly valid. Regarding the error - it just says that the index has `any` type implicitly, but you have _"noImplicitAny"_ compiler option enabled

Comment: Hint: try to understand what "index signature" means.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> It contains an unknown number of objects of the same type.

Maybe with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) interface `BigObject<T>` for your [dictionary](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)?

```
interface BigObject<T> {
    [index: string]: T
}

let bigObject: BigObject<object> = {}
Object.keys(bigObject).forEach(key => {
  console.log(bigObject[key])
})
```

Here I wrote the type `object` in `let bigObject: BigObject<object>`. You can use a better type.

Comment: thanks! :-)
So it seems, the combination of my above approach with the definition of an indexable type (interface that defines index signature) is the way to go then...

Comment: @Marcel Yes. You could just use an inline type definition: `let bigObject: {[index: string]: object} = {}`. It is the proposition of @Aleksey L., but with `object` instead of `any`.

Comment: @Paleo...yeah, true. in my case I am going to stick to an interface since I have multiple similar objects which will be processed together. thanks again!

Comment: just as an addition for anyone trying to do this as well:

with TypeScript 2.2.2 the handling of string indexing for objects with index signatures has been simplified.

so, now instead of writing bigObjectt[key] in the above examples, you can just write bigObject.key ! :-)

here is a link to the relevant TypeScript blog post ...
[link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/02/22/announcing-typescript-2-2/)

Comment: @Marcel: Nope. If `key` is a variable that contains `abc`, `bigObject.key` will not access to `bigObject.abc`. You have to keep the syntax `bigObject[key]` here. By the way, can you validate my answer?

Answer (score 37):

### for..in

When looking at the Typescript documentation ([Typescript: Iterators and Generators](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html)), we see that the for..in syntax will iterate over the **keys** of the object.

> for..in returns a list of keys on the object being iterated, whereas for..of returns a list of values of the numeric properties of the object being iterated.

We can use that to our advantage to index into our object and get the strongly typed value:

```
// Go through each key of the indexed object:
for (const key in indexedObject)
{
   // Get the indexed item by the key:
   const indexedItem = indexedObject[key];
   // Now we have the item.
   
   // Use it...
}
```

### Solution

We can use that to get an elegant solution to the question:

```
// Go through each key in the bigObject:
for (const key in bigObject)
{
   // Get the strongly typed value with this name:
   const value = bigObject[key];
   // Now we have the the strongly typed value for this key (depending on how bigObject was typed in the first place).
   
   // Do something interesting with the property of bigObject...
}
```

As pointed out by [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) (Thank you):

> This solution works in JavaScript, but gives TypeScript errors when using --strict compiler options.

Comment: Is there a method to do this in-line, e.g. something like `Object.keys`  that returns the keys that are also iterated over using `in`? (correctly typed)

Comment: When I do this, I still the issue. `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'CustomList'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'CustomList'.`

Comment: @TonyBrasunas I added a solution below that addresses this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003532/13214938

Comment: This solution works in JavaScript, but gives TypeScript errors when using `--strict` compiler options.  You might want to [edit] to mention that, or I can do so if you don't mind.

Answer (score 31):

After playing with it a while I found a solution that makes the TS compiler happy. Declare the key outside the for loop:

```
type TObj = { 
  key1: string; 
  key2: string 
}

const obj: TObj = {
  key1: "foo",
  key2: "bar"
};

// Declare the key outside the for loop
let t: keyof TObj;

for(t in obj) {
  obj[t]; // no compiler error
}
```

Comment: This is the chosen solution.  One line extra and doesn't make me rip my hair out.

Comment: Wow: this `let key` trick before the `for` loop made it!

Answer (score 10):

##### Short Solution

For those who like to save on typing and avoid both the implicit any error and "the left hand side of a for...in statement must be a string" error, here is the shortest way I know of to iterate the properties of an object in Typescript. Note no interface or class.

```
export const collection = {property1: "", property2: ""};

let key: keyof typeof collection;
for (key in collection) collection[key] = key; // or other operation
```

Here we assign all the right hand sides of the properties to be some function of their key name--in this example, identity. Should compile in `tsc` with no errors.

##### Answering the Original Poster's Question

If you have a class instead of an object literal, you can use `keyof` followed by the class name. If you have some Object with unknown keys as the **original poster** asked about, you could try an inline type (see first line below):

```
export const collection: { [key: string]: any } = // inline type
  { Property1: "", Property2: "" }; // value could come from any source

let key: keyof typeof collection;
for (key in collection) collection[key] = key; // or other operation
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work:

```
type InferKey<T> = T extends Partial<Record<infer K, any>> ? K : never;
type InferValue<T> = T extends Partial<Record<any, infer V>> ? V : never;
/** Returns strongly-typed entries of obj. */
export const toEntries = <T extends Partial<Record<string, any>>>(obj: T) => {
  return Object.entries(obj) as [InferKey<T>, InferValue<T>][];
};


/** An example key type. */
export type JustificationFilterName =
  | "propositionId"
  | "propositionCompoundId"
  | "sourceExcerptParaphraseId"
  | "writQuoteId"
  | "writId"
  | "url";
export type JustificationFilters = Partial<
  Record<JustificationFilterName, string>
>;

/** Example usage: */
for (const [filterName, filterValue] of toEntries(filters)) {
  switch (filterName) {
    case "propositionId": {
      // ...
      break;
    }
    case "propositionCompoundId": {
      // ...
      break;
    }
    ...
    default:
      // filterName will have type `never` if your cases above are exhaustive,
      // and you can type newExhaustedEnumError to accept `never` so that TS
      // will catch non-exhaustive switch statements.
      throw newExhaustedEnumError(filterName);
  }
}
```