# TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to iterate over the properties of an object in TypeScript. There's a similar question [How to iterate over keys of a generic object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389414/how-to-iterate-over-keys-of-a-generic-object-in-typescript) but the answer doesn't work in this case.

I'm using a for..in loop as suggested in the answer but I still get an error:

`TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Foo'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Foo'.`

```
interface Foo {
  a: number;
  b: number;
}

doSomething(foo?: Foo) {
  if (foo)
      for (const key in foo)
        console.log(foo[key])
                    ~~~~~~~~
}
```

The answer to this question [TypeScript - ts(7053)...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759505/typescript-ts7053-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression/62759681#62759681) explains that you cannot use a generic string as an index for an object with named properties. TypeScript can't guarantee that the string will actually match a property name. But I'm using for..in so TypeScript can actually guarantee that `key` matches a property name.

Why does it not work for me? What's the right way to get rid of this TypeScript error?

Comment: The accepted answer to the question linked above does not use `for..in`.  You can either widen `Foo` to `{[k: string]: number}` as in the accepted answer, or you can use the `let key: keyof Foo` trick from one of the other answers.  The top listed answer to the question you looked does not work as-is in TypeScript.

Comment: The most upvoted answer uses for..in. But why does it not work? Am I wrong in saying that TypeScript can safely guarantee that the properties reffered by `key` exist? I don't want to widen the type delcaration of `Foo`. It's supposed to have only the named properties.

Comment: `keyof` actually works, thanks for the hint. I overlooked it in the other answers. But why is it necessary? TypeScript can clearly see that the `key` exists?

Comment: It cannot safely guarantee because object types in TS are open; `interface Bar extends Foo { c: string }` means you can bass a `Bar` into `doSomething()` and one of the keys will be `"c"` and the value will be `string`.  That means TypeScript cannot guarantee that the type of the value will be anything more specific than `unknown`, for arbitrary key `key`.  You either have to assert that `key` is `keyof Foo` and deal with the consequences if something like `Bar` is passed in, or widen to a type that will complain about `Bar`, like `{[k: string]: number}`.

Comment: It's not that `key` doesn't exist, it's that it might be `any` property whatsoever due to TS structural subtyping.  I've linked to some other q/a above which go into that more.  It also links to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) which should hopefully explain the issue.

Comment: Oh so the problem is, if you pass in `Bar`, the type of `foo[key]` would be unknown. It wouldn't lead to an error because the `foo[key]` property access is safe, but the resulting type isn't known anymore which is not allowed in TypeScript I guess?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I really struggle with TypeScript errors messages, I don't understand what they want to say.

Comment: I have one more question if you're still here @jcalz. Actually I'm passing `foo[key]` to `JSON.stringify(foo[key])` and I have two subclasses of `Foo`. So saying `key as keyof Foo` is wrong. The type of `foo[key]` is unknown. But I don't need to know the type because stringify takes values of any type. So can I explicitly declare `foo[key]` as unknown? The error message criticizes that it's implicitly 'any'. I want to make it explicitly unknown. Not sure how thouh. `foo[key] as unknown` doesn't work.

Comment: Don't pass in `Foo` then, pass in `{[k: string]: unknown}` or `{[k: string]: any}`, or `Foo & {[k: string]: unknown}` etc.  It's kind of hard to hash things out in comments so you might want to open a new question if you need more in-depth help

Comment: I don't know how to generalize that question. Often it ends up as another duplicate. Thanks a lot for your help though!