# How to loop through the keys of a parameter that can be one of 3 different interfaces in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a function like this one:

```
function myFunc(input: A | B | C) {
    let key: keyof A | keyof B | keyof C;
    for(key in input)
    {
        let temp = input[key];
        console.log(temp);
    }
}
```

with the definitions for A B and C being as follows:

```
interface A {
    u: number,
    t: string,
    s: boolean,
    r: boolean
}
interface B {
    w: string,
    v: string
}
interface C {
    z: string,
    y: number,
    x: boolean
}
```

And I tried using the method in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389414/how-to-iterate-over-keys-of-a-generic-object-in-typescript) to create a variable that can be used to loop through the properties of the input object regardless of which interface it is an instance of, however I'm getting the following error:

```
TS2405: The left-hand side of a 'for...in' statement must be of type 'string' or 'any'.
```

However if I try to define 'key' like so:

```
let key:any;
```

I get a different error:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'A | B | C'.
```

Is there a way to define 'key' such that I can make this just one function, or would I have to split this up into 3 functions, 1 for each interface?

Comment: You could make it generic [as shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxzqZw), or you could widen `input` to something with a string index signature [as shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQLq1W).  Do either of those meet your needs? If so I could write an answer (or find a suitable dupe target); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That second playground link seems to be working, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't make it very easy to loop over keys of an object in a way that lets you index with those keys, as describe in [How to iterate over keys of a generic object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43389414/2887218).  Most of the techniques in the answers there work for various use cases, but the one you have here with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of interfaces won't work, because [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) when acting on a union gives the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the keys, meaning just  the keys that appear in *all* the union members.  This is the safest thing for the compiler to do, but it loses track of the *correlation* between the object type and its key.

The language can't really handle using union types in an arbitrary way; the general issue is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  If you want to perform a single action that works for a union of types, you can refactor to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) instead (which is part of the solution to ms/TS#30581 described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)):

```
function myFunc<T extends A | B | C>(input: T) {
  let key: keyof T;
  for (key in input) {
    let temp = input[key]; // okay
    //  ^? let temp: T[keyof T]
    console.log(temp);
  }
}
```

Another approach you can take is to widen your input type from `A | B | C` to the type `Record<string, any>` or the equivalent `{[k: string]: any}`. This type has an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) meaning that it will allow any key whatsoever, and the property type at that key is given the intentionally loose [`any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any):

```
function myFunc(_input: A | B | C) {
  const input: { [k: string]: any } = _input;
  for (const key in input) { 
    let temp = input[key]; // okay
    //  ^? any
    console.log(temp);
  }
}
```

Neither way is perfect.  Depending on your needs you might want to just give up on a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop and use [the `Object.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead, which gives you both keys and values at once:

```
function myFunc(input: A | B | C) {
  Object.entries(input).forEach(([key, temp]) => {
    temp
    // ^? any
    console.log(temp);
  })
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-jWgBe2c9wYMiHtjudlmoYcDYANQA)